# How to customize next-auth signup?

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I would like to customize my nextjs application using next-auth such that upon signup, I will create a default org/tenant for this user and use that generated org in the url path `https://app.myapplication.io/[lang]/[org]`. Where should this code be placed? Currently, the only option I see is in [the `signIn` callback](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks#sign-in-callback). This is a multi-tenancy design problem I'm trying to tackle.